# "OSError: [Errno 48] Address already in use" when trying to bind two sockets to localhost but different ports

Tags: python, sockets, networking, udp, localhost

Just started learning networks so this question may sound stupid...

I was trying to create two very simple udp servers that communicate with each other. I gave them each a socket that binds to 'localhost' but to different ports:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(('localhost', server_port)) # server_port will be different
```

I fired up two processes in my terminal and ran into the error in the second process and it pointed to the second line in the code.

Did it fail because we simply can't bind more than one socket to 'localhost'? What's going on here?

Thanks!

Comment: Too little detail, you should add the actual error message and the port you have chosen. Multiple services on localhost is normal. More likely you've picked a port already in use. Also best to avoid privileged ports.

Comment: server_port **isn't** different even though you think it is